# Probability with two uniformly distributed cost

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two uniformly distributed costs that are random and statistically independent. They are 3,000 to 6,000 and 3,000 to 12,000. I am trying to find the probability that the total cost of these two would be less than 9,000.

I am unsure of how to approach is but I did (x-a)/(b-a) to find the probability it would be less than 9,000 for each cost respectively.

For 3000 to 12,000 I got (9k-3k)/(12k-3k) = 6/9 = 2/3.

For 3000 to 6000 it will always be less than 9,000.

So would the probability that the total cost be less than 9,000 be 2/3?

Comment: Try find joint distribution f(x,y) (which should be easy since independent) from this you want $P(X+Y\leq 9000)=\int\int_{D}f(x,y)$ where D is the region that should be intersection of region under y=9000-x and region of support of joint pdf

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I am confused on the values of X and Y though. How would I get those values?

Comment: Oh I just used X and Y to represent random variables from your question $X\sim Uni(3000,6000)$ and $Y\sim Uni(3000,12000)$

Comment: So does that mean I do the integrals with the limits of the two distributions? Sorry I am new to this stuff.

Comment: oh ok, so if you have two independent random variables X, Y with corresponding pdfs $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$ their joint $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ in your example you have unifmrom so pdf for $Uni(a,b)$ is just $\frac{1}{b-a}$ after finding joint pdf from there you would integrate over that region D as I described

Comment: Also what you calculated seem to probability that both cost are less than 9000 or in other words $P(max(X,Y)\leq 9000)$ which is different than total cost is less than 9000 since total cost is $X+Y$

Answer (score 3):

Just draw a rectangle in the coordinate plane. Let the $x$-axis be the first cost, and the $y$-axis be the second. Then we have a rectangle corresponding to the relevant values of the two costs, see the diagram below.

Then look at the graph of the inequality $x+y<9000$. It cuts out a portion of the rectangle, over which the total cost will be less than $9000$. So just figure out what fraction of the rectangle that portion is.

[image]

Bad Paint sketch, not to scale.

The answer should be
$$\frac{3000\times3000/2}{3000\times9000}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: That all makes sense. Thank you for the sketch as well.